# Rewrite all image src to up one level

Tags: image, .htaccess

Hi can I rewrite all img src tags to up one level?Currently my image tags are

```
/folder/abc.jpg
```

I want to change to

```
../folder/abc.jpg?
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/(.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))$ /$1
```

in the htaccess file in your document root (the folder the the "folder" folder is in).